# onclosing form return value

Tags: .net, vb.net

Is there a way tha a form returns a value? something like ...

```
sub main() 

   Dim task as new TaskForm()
   dim res as integer=0
   res = task.opendialog()

end sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [`ShowDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), you can set the form's [`DialogResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult.aspx) property to a value.  Keep in mind that the form can't return arbitrary results this way, only the values of the [`DialogResult` enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dialogresult.aspx).

Otherwise, you'd have to set the form's [`Tag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) Property and manually retrieve it after the form is closed, but before you discard the reference to it.

Answer (score 1):

It depends a bit on what you want to have returned. If you want to show a dialog and figure out which button that was used for closing it (OK, Cancel, ...) you can display the form using the [`ShowDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx) method, which returns a [`DialogResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dialogresult.aspx) value:

```
DialogResult result = theForm.ShowDialog();
if (result == DialogResult.OK)
{
    // OK was clicked
}
```

If you want to return some other value, the easiest way is to expose this through a property on the form, or to provide a static method in the form that will create an instance of it, collect the needed input and than return the data:

```
class NameInputForm : Form
{
    // form initialization / construction left out for brevity, but let's assume
    // it contains a TextBox control called UserNameTextBox and a button with
    // its DialogResult property set to OK

    public static string GetNameFromUser()
    {
        using (NameInputForm form = new NameInputForm())
        {
            if (form.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                return form.UserNameTextBox.Text;
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```